# Magento : Invalid Form Key After Migration

Tags: admin, magento-1

I know question has been asked alot, but none of suggestions work for me.

I migrated files and database to my localhost (Windows/Xampp)

The front-end of the site is working fine, but I cant log in to admin part due to this invalid form key.

I tried all the options, I could find in other posts which are:

- deleting web/cookie/cookie_domain and web/cookie/cookie_path records in db
- clear Magento cache files
- clear browser cache
- try other browsers
- editing session_set_cookie_params()
- adding php_value max_input_vars 75000 to php.ini

What else can I try to get into the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, the timezone set in the database, didn't match the timezone in the config.xml.

the db record was in `core_config_data` with path `general/locale/timezone`
in config.xml it was inbetween `<timezone></timezone>`

Making sure both were set to the same values solved my problem